# Is there any reason not to use StrictPragma most of the time?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, evaluation

There will be support of https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/StrictPragma in the future version of GHC.

So evaluation could be similar to other languages like C, JavaScript, etc.

Strict evaluation looks better for performance and understanding of code execution.

Yes, there are functions like (&&) where you need to use lazy parameters, but it should be so often and you can use `~`.

So, is there any reason not to use StrictPragma most of the time?

Comment: I think this will be highly opinionated - in this case it would mean that we would need some strict_base as well - IMO Haskell should stick to it's lazy roots - if you have to much trouble with you can always choose another language (most are strict) - for me it's one of the great points of Haskell that I can play/try with a lazy-by-default language

Comment: "in the future version of Haskell" - what version, exactly? (Of GHC, not of Haskell)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on the data type at hand. On lists it would be quite harmful.

```
f n = foldl' (+) 0 [1..n]
```

can be run in constant space (even without deforestation). If the list type were strict, it would require linear space.

Infinite lists idioms become impossible

```
head $ filter p [1..]
zip xs [1..]
fibs = 0:1:zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

In high-performance numeric code, strictness does often lead to better performance.

Comment: But, is it more about data structures rather than strictness? You can create lazy or infinity list in any language.

Comment: @ais try to redefine `foldl'` in a strict-language where you just use a lazy-data structure ... you will soon find that the abstraction leaks and that you have to change your `foldl'`s signature as well